# apex trigger with cross objects

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an object "shipment__c" with fields, among others, "CIF_Value__c", "Exporter_Account__c", "Shipment_Account__c", "Invoice_Name__c".
I have another object called "Account_Move_*c" with fields "Amount*_c", "From_account__c", "To_Account_*c", "Description*_c".

I'm trying to automatically create a record on "Account_Move_*c" each time a record on "Shipment*_c" is either created or updated.  It doesn't seem too complicated to do, but I'm stuck on how to call the variables related to "Shipment__C".

Here is how I've attempted:

```
trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 on Shipment__c (after insert) {
    List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();
    for (Shipment__c oShippment : trigger.New) {
        Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
        oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c;
        oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShippment.Invoice_Name__c;
        oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShippment.Exporter_Name__c;
        oAccounting_Move.To_Account__c = oShippment.Shipment_Account__c;
        oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount__c = oShippment.CIF_Value__c;
     listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);
    }
    insert listaccountingmove;
}
```

and I'm getting this error.  Any ideas?

Error:Apex trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountingMoveLoading2: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, From_Account: id value of incorrect type: a05b00000045RNDAA2: [From_Account__c]: Trigger.AccountingMoveLoading2: line 14, column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franky,
Field From_Account__c is probably expecting an Account object (id), but your are passing it Exporter_Name__c which is possibly a String.
Rup

Comment: You were absolutely right, I've selected the wrong field from the object.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Pls check the spelling of oShippment. It has a double 'p' in the for loop and in your assignment you are using oShipment.ETD__c . There is only one 'p' there